# Is it possible to create a DNS entry for a DFS file share

Tags: networking, dns, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm trying to setup a DNS friendly name for a DFS file share.

The DFS share looks like this:

```
\\mydomain.com\dfs\location\dev\myfolder
```

The DNS entry I want to create looks like this:

```
\\myfolder.test.mydomain.com
```

Can this even be done? If so, what are some good resources that can help accomplish this?

Comment: You could certainly create a CNAME that points myfolder.test.mydomain.com at mydomain.com, but I think that if a user accessed the DFS share by that name it might fail, but why don't you give it a try and let us know.  :)

Comment: Not brave enough for the "try it and see" method. :)

Comment: You don't have to be brave... it's a no-risk effort. If you create a CNAME and you can connect to it, great! If not and you can't, you can still connect to the original name \\mydomain.com\dfs\...